# Setting Tab Index in WebForm

Tags: asp.net

In a WebForm I have

1. TextBox
2. FreeTextBox(Third party tool)
3. CheckBox

I gave tab index value for TextBox as 1 and CheckBox as 2 by setting TextBox to default focus.

The Problem is after the page is loaded when I press tab, insted of moving focus to checkbox, URL bar of the browser is getting focused.

Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

In what browser are you seeing the behavior? I've tested it in Firefox with no problemas.

Why don't you try with a simple form and then start adding other elements to see when it fails? (maybe the third party component is the culprit)

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false"
    CodeBehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="WebApplication1._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head runat="server">
    <title>my test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form runat="server" defaultFocus="txtBox1">
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox1" TabIndex="1"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        <asp:TextBox runat="server" ID="txtBox2" TabIndex="3"></asp:TextBox> <br />
        <asp:CheckBox runat="server" ID="chkBox1" TabIndex="2" /><br />
        <asp:Button UseSubmitBehavior="true" runat="server" ID="btn1" text="submit" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```